# Is there a express javascript es6 string template engine

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, template-engine, ecmascript-6

I've been using .EJS in Cody (a nodejs cms system). Is there a rendering engine out there that uses ES6 string templates as syntax? It would be nice to replace the <%= ... %> by ${ ... }  easier to read for the Java JSP / JSTL programmers.

Comment: off-topic??  Well if these people have an answer to my question... please...

Answer (score 2):

EJS lets you define your own delimiters, you can change them like this

```
var ejs = require('ejs');

ejs.open = '${';
ejs.close = '}';
```

The `=` and `-` for echoing escaped and unescaped can't be easily changed though, so you'd have to do `${-string}`

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that, but I was interested in a new/existing rendering engine that uses the ES6 String Template functionality to do the substitution. Sooner or later it would be:
1) quick -- as this would probably be native code. 
2) standard -- more and more people will be using the std ES6 string templates.